# How to apply Flyway Java migrations before Jooq generation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jooq, flyway

We have a project with SpringBoot and JOOQ. Recently we have started using Flyway for database migrations. Initially we were using only SQL file migrations and all was well.
Now we've decided to have Java migrations as well for some situations which are more complex than just a few SQL statements.
However, I've noticed that though the SQL migrations run at the beginning of the build (we have set it up like that so that when JOOQ generates code the DDLs have been applied already), the Java migrations run much later, after the compilation and the unit tests tasks.
This causes an issue because if say we have 4 migrations to run:
1 - sqlmigration01
2 - javamigration02
3 - sqlmigration03
4 - javamigration04
It would run the SQL migrations first and the java migrations last, so out of the intended order.
Is there a way to run the Java migrations before the JOOQ code generation happens? That way we could run java migrations only and ensure the proper order of execution of the migrations.
The only solution I've come up so far is to have a separate project just for the migrations and build that project first, then build the main project.

Edit: relevant build.gradle configuration

```
project.tasks.getByName('compileJava').dependsOn -= 'generateJooqSource'

// sets up Gradle to run Flyway DB migration scripts before running JOOQ
project.tasks.getByName('generateJooqSource').dependsOn 'migrateLocal'

task migrateLocal(type: org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayMigrateTask) {
    url = System.getenv('url')
    user = System.getenv('user')
    password = System.getenv('pwd')
}

flyway {
    schemas = ['schemaname']
    locations = ["filesystem:some/path"]
    baselineOnMigrate = true
    mixed = true
    baselineVersion = 2.0
    baselineDescription = "BaselineDesc"
}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your Maven / Gradle biild setup?

Comment: Added the relevant bits.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.5.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>migrate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <driver>${db.driver}</driver>
                    <url>${db.url}</url>
                    <user>${db.username}</user>
                    <password>${db.password}</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>3.14.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jdbc>
                        <driver>${db.driver}</driver>
                        <url>${db.url}</url>
                        <user>${db.username}</user>
                        <password>${db.password}</password>
                    </jdbc>
                    <generator>
                        <database>
                            <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                            <includes>.*</includes>
                            <excludes/>
                            <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
                        </database>
                        <target>
```

all magic is in

when you run build project maven will run first flayway, second jooq and other like compile and tests